# No rig object when exporting character from blender to unity

Tags: export, unity

I am trying to export my character from blender to unity, everything is being exported correctly except for the rig. I can't find the rig and also the body parts of the character have no root bone. Which is usually to be found in the rig object. When I select the FBX file I can access the rig tag.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching I found out that in unity when you select the FBX file and go to the rig tab I had ticked the option "Optimize Game Objects" which caused the rig to disappear. After unticking the rig was back in the FBX and in my game object.